# how to use find -regex ... what regex dialect is it?

Tags: regex, find

I'm using this series of commands very often, to list all files but excluding sub-directories like `.git` and others,

```
find \( -name .git -or -name node_modules \) -prune -or -ls
```

depends on different project's structure, might have more `<unwanted-dir>`

```
find \( -name .git -or -name node_modules -or -name another-unwanted-dir \) -prune -or -ls
```

want to merge into a single regex, like

```
find -regex './(.git|node_modules)' -prune -or -ls
```

but this does not work, have tried `-regextype posix` or other types, but haven't figured out one working

**Update**: this one indeed works, I found the reason is the `-regextype` has to be given before `-regex`

```
find -regextype posix-egrep -regex './(.git|node_modules|another-dir)' -prune -or -ls
```

not after: this one is not working

```
find -regex './(.git|node_modules|another-dir)' -regextype posix-egrep -prune -or -ls
```

But, what is the default `regextype` ? Can anyone make a regex work without specifying `regextype` ? (to make the command length shorter...)

Comment: You need to escape `.` in every flavor of regexp

Comment: Use `-regextype help` to see a list of all the possible types.

Comment: Something like `-regextype posix-extended -regex '(.*/)?(\.git|node_modules)$'`

Comment: `-regextype posix-egrep` should work for your needs

Comment: Don't forget that the regexp has to match the entire pathname, so you need to start with `.*` to skip over the directories.

Comment: As per `man find`, the default one uses basic regular expressions (BRE's) (same as default `grep`). Use `man re_format` to get more infomation. Basically you need to use `\(`, `\)` and `\|` (and remember to use `\.`).

Comment: gnu find and BSD find have different way tot use regex